# Get latlong at a distance on a path

Tags: javascript, distance, latitude-longitude

I have 2 decimal point in lat/lon. I want to divide the line drawn by lat/lon into parts each at a specified distance, lets say 'x' -- all except the last segment will be of length x -- and I need the lat/longs of the dividing points.

I tried searching but couldn't find anything involving 2 lat/longs.
Are they any libraries to do this, currently I am using JavaScript for my implementation.

Comment: welcome to GIS@SE, please edit your question to reflect the Software Package/Applications/libraries you are using and add them to the tags at the bottom of the question. It makes it a lot easier for people to provide an answer when they know that information

Comment: Look at geodesic path from the Javascript port of [geographiclib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/scripts/geod-calc.html). If you are dealing with short distances, basic interpolation should be ok, but you haven't given enough information to tell.